# How can I concatenate files, keeping track of the name of the file in a column?

Tags: bash

I have several tab delimited files that look like this ( I am presenting two examples).

sim9_more_stuff.out:

```
0       31492.4941084098        599.505895270519                
1       32091.999959    4.1727117e-05
...
```

sim999_more_stuff.out:

```
0       23455        5.05895270519                
1       3959    477
...
```

I would need to concatenate all these files, but keeping track of the identifier of the file in a column, like this:

```
0       31492.4941084098        599.505895270519   sim9             
1       32091.999959    4.1727117e-05              sim9    
...
0       23455        5.05895270519        sim999              
1       3959    477                       sim999
```

I thought that I could use something like the following loop and, after that, the cat command:

```
for f in file1 file2 file3; do sed -i "s/$/\t$f/" $f; done
```

But doing that would write the complete filenames, and I only want the identifier.

Could you propose a more accurate and automatized way of doing this? Thanks a lot for your time and sorry for the naive question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an `awk` solution like this:

```sh
awk '{split(FILENAME, a, /_/); print $0 "\t" a[1]}' *.out

0       23455        5.05895270519  sim999
1       3959    477 sim999
0       31492.4941084098        599.505895270519    sim9
1       32091.999959    4.1727117e-05   sim9
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- by `identifier` OP means everything the comes before the first `_`
- all filenames have at least one `_`

Using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to obtain the `identifier`, eg:

```
$ f='sim999_more_stuff.out'
$ echo "${f%%_*}"
sim999
```

Tweaking OP's current code:

```
for f in *stuff.out; do sed -i "s/$/\t${f%%_*}/" $f; done
```

This will add the `identifier` to the end of every line for all source files **and** write these changes back to the source file.  If the loop is run a second time then the `identifier` will be appended to every line, again.

If OP wants to maintain the source files in their current state (ie, sans the `identifier` appended to each line), but capture all of the modified lines to a new file, consider:

```
for f in *stuff.out; do sed "s/$/\t${f%%_*}/" $f; done > all.out
```

This has the added benefit that repeated runs will *not* append an extra `identifier` onto the end of every line for each `for` loop invocation.